# How to return each individual row in the results?

Tags: search, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created an API that searches sheet 2 in a spreadsheet for a keyword and returns the number of the row of the cell that the key word was found in. I want to copy and paste all the rows from sheet 2 on to sheet 1. I can't get the script to copy and paste them all.

```
function executeSearch() {
  //establishing search sheet
  var SSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var SS = SSS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var searchTerm = SS.getRange('B3').getValue();
  //establishing the data sheet
  var DS = SSS.getSheetByName('Sheet2');


  var completeSearch = DS.createTextFinder(searchTerm).findAll();
  for (var i = 0; i < completeSearch.length; i++) {
    var range = completeSearch[i];    
    var resultsCells = range.getA1Notation(); //get the cell location of the search data cell
    var row = range.getRow(); //get the rows that the search data is in

DS.getRange(row, 1, 1, DS.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(SS.getRange(8, 1, 1, DS.getMaxColumns()));

  }
```

Comment: You have copied all rows into the same (8-th) row of the SS (see the last code line). Is this a mistake?

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин Ohhhh, yes it is! How would I define the ranges so that it copies each row (with the search result in it) down the rows, if that makes sense? The main issue I have is that it doesn't copy all of the results, even if there are multiple rows. It always copies just one row from the original data sheet. The row variable returns answers like this: ```[19-07-07 00:43:30:639 PDT] 3.0
[19-07-07 00:43:30:642 PDT] 9.0
[19-07-07 00:43:30:645 PDT] 13.0```

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин those results are the rows. I need to copy each row by number into the other sheet. I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is copying the data to the same row each time:

```
DS.getRange(row, 1, 1, DS.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(SS.getRange(8, 1, 1, DS.getMaxColumns()));
```

To get the code to write the data to new rows, you can change it to:

```
DS.getRange(row, 1, 1, DS.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(SS.getRange(8 + i, 1, 1, DS.getMaxColumns()));
```

But this isn't efficient when you have a large number of results. You are repeatedly calling the sheet for writing each row.

It would be more efficient to first write all the search results to an array. And then to call the sheet just once to write all the data to the rows in one go.

```
function executeSearch() {

  //establishing search sheet
  var SSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var SS = SSS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var searchTerm = SS.getRange('B3').getValue();

  //establishing the data sheet
  var DS = SSS.getSheetByName('Sheet2');  

  var completeSearch = DS.createTextFinder(searchTerm).findAll();
  var searchResults = []; // Create an array to store the values of the search results

  for (var i = 0; i < completeSearch.length; i++) {
    var range = completeSearch[i];
    var row = range.getRow(); //get the rows that the search data is in
    var values = DS.getRange(row, 1, 1, DS.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
    searchResults.push(values[0]);
  }

  SS.getRange(8, 1, searchResults.length, searchResults[0].length).setValues(searchResults);
}
```

The only thing to watch out for in this script is that it will write values to the sheet and not formulas.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. This took me forever!